# Equivalent of Cons Pattern from F# in Rust for Strings

Tags: rust, tail

I am experimenting with Rust by implementing a small F# snippet of mine.

I am at the point where I want to destructure a string of characters. Here is the F#:

```ml
 let rec internalCheck acc = function
    | w :: tail when Char.IsWhiteSpace(w) -> 
        internalCheck acc tail
    | other
    | matches
    | here
```

..which can be called like this: `internalCheck [] "String here"` where the `::` operator signifies the right hand side is the "rest of the list".

So I checked the Rust documentation and there are examples for destructuring vectors like this:

```
let v = vec![1,2,3];

match v {
    [] => ...
    [first, second, ..rest] => ...
}
```

..etc. However this is now behind the `slice_patterns` feature gate. I tried something similar to this:

```
match input.chars() {
    [w, ..] => ...
}
```

Which informed me that feature gates require non-stable releases to use.

So I downloaded `multirust` and installed the latest nightly I could find (`2016-01-05`) and when I finally got the `slice_patterns` feature working ... I ran into endless errors regarding syntax and "rest" (in the above example) not being allowed.

So, is there an equivalent way to destructure a string of characters, utilizing `::`-like functionality ... in Rust? Basically I want to match 1 character with a guard and use "everything else" in the expression that follows.

It is perfectly acceptable if the answer is "No, there isn't". I certainly cannot find many examples of this sort online anywhere and the slice pattern matching doesn't seem to be high on the feature list.

(I will happily delete this question if there is something I missed in the Rust documentation)

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://is.gd/h9U1SI. Perhaps the syntax have changed? Still worth a full answer.

Comment: @ArtemGr Yes, sorry, that seems to work. However I can't seem to get it working on a string of characters. That was the main point of the question (if that wasn't clear - should I perhaps rephrase?).

Comment: By the way @ArtemGr, thank you for the playground link - I wasn't aware Rust had a playground like that (thumbsup).

Comment: How about http://is.gd/WgkdSw? There seems to be a temporary problem with playground but on my workstation it prints "matched... 1 matched... 2".

Comment: Geez thats close to what I'm after @ArtemGr. I don't suppose theres a name for that `b` prefix I could use to continue investigating?

Comment: It's a byte literal: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference.html#byte-literals; see https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference.html#literals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the pattern matching with a `byte` slice:

```
#![feature(slice_patterns)]

fn internal_check(acc: &[u8]) -> bool {
    match acc {
        &[b'-', ref tail..] => internal_check(tail),
        &[ch, ref tail..] if (ch as char).is_whitespace() => internal_check(tail),
        &[] => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}

fn main() {
    for s in ["foo", "bar", "   ", " - "].iter() {
        println!("text '{}', checks? {}", s, internal_check(s.as_bytes()));
    }
}
```

You can use it with a `char` slice (where `char` is a Unicode Scalar Value):

```
#![feature(slice_patterns)]

fn internal_check(acc: &[char]) -> bool {
    match acc {
        &['-', ref tail..] => internal_check(tail),
        &[ch, ref tail..] if ch.is_whitespace() => internal_check(tail),
        &[] => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}

fn main() {
    for s in ["foo", "bar", "   ", " - "].iter() {
        println!("text '{}', checks? {}",
                 s, internal_check(&s.chars().collect::<Vec<char>>()));
    }
}
```

But as of now it doesn't work with a `&str` (producing [E0308](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0308)). Which I think is for the best since `&str` is neither here nor there, it's a `byte` slice under the hood but Rust tries to guarantee that it's a valid UTF-8 and tries to remind you to work with `&str` in terms of unicode sequences and characters rather than bytes. So to efficiently match on the `&str` we have to explicitly use the `as_bytes` method, essentially telling Rust that "we know what we're doing".

That's my reading, anyway. If you want to dig deeper and into the source code of the Rust compiler you might start with [issue 1844](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/1844) and browse the commits and issues linked there.

> Basically I want to match 1 character with a guard and use "everything
>   else" in the expression that follows.

If you only want to match on a *single* character then using the [chars](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) iterator to get the characters and matching on the character itself might be better than converting the entire UTF-8 `&str` into a `&[char]` slice. For instance, with the [chars](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) iterator you don't have to allocate the memory for the characters array.

```
fn internal_check(acc: &str) -> bool {
    for ch in acc.chars() {
        match ch {
            '-' => (),
            ch if ch.is_whitespace() => (),
            _ => return false,
        }
    }
    return true;
}

fn main() {
    for s in ["foo", "bar", "   ", " - "].iter() {
        println!("text '{}', checks? {}", s, internal_check(s));
    }
}
```

You can also use the [chars](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) iterator to split the `&str` on the Unicode Scalar Value boundary:

```
fn internal_check(acc: &str) -> bool {
    let mut chars = acc.chars();
    match chars.next() {
        Some('-') => internal_check(chars.as_str()),
        Some(ch) if ch.is_whitespace() => internal_check(chars.as_str()),
        None => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}

fn main() {
    for s in ["foo", "bar", "   ", " - "].iter() {
        println!("text '{}', checks? {}", s, internal_check(s));
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that as of now Rust provides no guarantees of optimizing this tail-recursive function into a loop. (Tail call optimization would've been a welcome addition to the language but it wasn't implemented so far due to LLVM-related difficulties).

Comment: This is great! I really appreciate the time you took to put this together. There is literally 100 things in your samples (both the working and non working) that I can learn from. RE contributing.. I certainly would be up to the task in future.. once I am more comfortable with Rust. Thanks again! I really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome!  )
Also, I've locally checked all the samples in this answer and all of them should be working. If some of them aren't working for you then please give me a shout.

Comment: *due to LLVM-related difficulties* — also because TCO makes stack traces not look the same. IIRC, the keyword `become` is reserved for opting in to future TCO.

Comment: I realised I never accepted your answer @ArtemGr. Apologies for that.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead NP!  )

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so.  Slice patterns aren't likely to be amenable to this, either, since the "and the rest" part of the pattern goes *inside* the array pattern, which would imply some way of putting said pattern *inside* a string, which implies an escaping mechanism that doesn't exist.

In addition, Rust doesn't have a proper "concatenation" operator, and the operators it *does* have can't participate in destructuring.  So, I wouldn't hold your breath on this one.

Comment: Fair enough. This was a feature I enjoyed in F# so I did hope it was possible in Rust. Nonetheless it won't stop me from investigating Rust ... so thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just going to post this here... it seems to do what I want. As a simple test, this will just print every character in a string but print `Found a whitespace character` when it finds a whitespace character. It does this recursively and destructuring a vector of bytes. I must give a shout out to @ArtemGr who gave me the inspiration to look at working with bytes to see if that fixed the compiler issues I was having with `char`s.

There are no doubt memory issues I am unaware of as yet here (copying/allocations, etc; especially around the `String` instances)... but I'll work on those as I dig deeper in to the inner workings of Rust. It's also probably much more verbose than it needs to be.. this is just where I got to after a little tinkering.

```
#![feature(slice_patterns)]

use std::iter::FromIterator;
use std::vec::Vec;

fn main() {
    process("Hello world!".to_string());
}

fn process(input: String) {
    match input.as_bytes() {
        &[c, ref _rest..] if (c as char).is_whitespace() => { println!("Found a whitespace character"); process(string_from_rest(_rest)) },
        &[c, ref _rest..] => { println!("{}", c as char); process(string_from_rest(_rest)) },
        _ => ()
    }
}

fn string_from_rest(rest: &[u8]) -> String {
    String::from_utf8(Vec::from_iter(rest.iter().cloned())).unwrap()
}
```

Output:

```
H
e
l
l
o
Found a whitespace character
w
o
r
l
d
!
```

Obviously, as its testing against individual bytes (and only considering possible UTF-8 characters when rebuilding the string), its not going to work with wide characters. My actual use case only requires characters in the ASCII space .. so this is sufficient for now.

I guess, to work on wider characters the Rust pattern matching would require the ability to type coerce (which I don't believe you can do currently?), since a `Chars<'T>` iterator seems to be inferred as `&[_]`. That could just be my immaturity with the Rust language though during my other attempts.

Comment: +1 for going there. Unless you'll only work with ASCII, I think you need to work on a `&[char]` slice and the only bottleneck then would be efficiently obtaining it from a `&str`. I would've used a stack-allocated array for that (https://crates.io/crates/stack/) but it's a different story.